# Network bandwidth for a given Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, networking, firewall, bandwidth

We want to see how much bandwidth would our current DB consume if we move it from our system to cloud-based system where it crosses the firewall.

This is a prod system and it would be hard to setup any open source system to do this analysis.

It will be better to roughly get this information from the Oracle itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about looking at the SQL*Net stats of v$sysstat?

```
select * from v$sysstat where name like '%SQL*Net%';
```

This will give you all read/write SQL*Net I/O for all client activity including dblinks.

Comment: I saw that but wasn't able to figure out the time details around that. What does the value in the table mean?

Because of the above, I tried to join DBA_HIST_SYSSTAT and dba_hist_snapshot which made it complex.

Comment: That is total number of bytes since instance startup. So you can write some timing scripts to give you bytes per minute, for example. Not necessary to use DBA_HIST_SYSSTAT as all you need is some current bandwidth timing right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. So, you mean since the time system has been rebooted, this much of data is transferred?

Comment: Haha yes for our busy production system, in the last 10 days we have had 13 terabytes of SQL*Net IO.  BTW the server itself does a LOT more read IO than that, but that is not bandwidth.

Comment: So if you're going cloud, you need to limit the result sets coming back, for example using FIRST_ROWS hint.  Also limit ranges that users can put in to the application.  OR you can have users go VPN or Citrix or something, and your app carries on like before, and all the users get is a 'screen update'.  Lots of ways to do cloud.